# For every two points, that are not equal in $R^n$ it's possible to find neighbourhoods,such that they don't intersect

Tags: general-topology

I want to show, that for every two points, that are not equal in $R^n$ it's possible to find neighbourhoods,such that these neighbourhoods don't intersect

My idea: let distance between points is equal to $d(p,q) = \epsilon$.
Then let's take neighbourhood around points $p$ and $q$ with the radius $\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$: $U_{\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}}$, $V_{\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}}$.
So it means, that radius of each is equal to $\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$. And because neighbourhoods are open, hey don't intersect each other: 
$d(p,r_1) < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$ ;$d(q,r_2) < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$

So: $d(p,r_1) + d(q,r_2) < \epsilon$

But it seemse to easy and trivial. Is my proof correct?

Comment: The proof of them not intersecting each other is not clear from what you have written. You should assume that there is a common point, and then come up with a contradiction.

Comment: yes, this idea is correct

Comment: The idea is right - the proof is formally not sufficient. Assume there exists $x\in U\cap V$ and lead this to a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ and $y$ be points in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $\mathbb{R}^n$ has the standard Euclidean metric imposed on it and $x \neq y$.

Suppose $d(x, y) = \epsilon$, put $U =B_{(\mathbb{R}^n, d)}(x, \frac{\epsilon}{4}) $ and$V=B_{(\mathbb{R}^n, d)}(y, \frac{\epsilon}{4}) $.

Now assume $U \cap V \neq \emptyset$. Pick $z \in U \cap V$, then $d(x, z) < \frac{\epsilon}{4}$ and $d(z, y) < \frac{\epsilon}{4}$ and by the triangle inequality we have $d(x, y) = \epsilon \leq \frac{\epsilon}{4} + \frac{\epsilon}{4} = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ a contradiction. Hence $U \cap V = \emptyset$. $\square$.

---

Note that this result actually holds for general metric spaces.

Comment: With slightly more work (to keep track of when you have strict inequality) you can adapt this proof to the idea in the question, where we take neighborhoods with radius $\epsilon/2.$ But I recall making a habit of choosing $\epsilon/3$ in such cases in order to avoid the extra effort.